# I18n.locale = :en not always working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got a home page with two flags that allow to toggle between English and German. The two flags have a link to trigger an action on the controller, like this:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("germany-flag-24.png",:border=>0), {:controller=>:welcome, :action=>:set_de}%>
<%= link_to image_tag("united-kingdom-flag-24.png",:border=>0), :controller=>:welcome, :action=>:set_en  %>
```

In my controller I have the two actions defined:

```
def set_de
    I18n.locale = :de
    logger.debug "Locale=#{I18n.locale}"
    redirect_to :controller=>:welcome, :action=>:index
end
def set_en
    I18n.locale = :en
    logger.debug "Locale=#{I18n.locale}"
    redirect_to :controller=>:welcome, :action=>:index
end

def index
    logger.debug "Locale=#{I18n.locale}"

    ...
end
```

My routes.rb file is configured correctly, clicking on the flags works, the logger shows the respective actions in the controller being triggered.

Strange behaviour of the web page is: click on German, it shows German, click on English, it shows English, click on German again, it remains at English.

The logger.debug commands confirm this, set_de prints DE to the logfile but the index action then prints EN to the logfile.

This behaviour does not happen if I wait something like 5 to 10 seconds between clicking again on the language icons.

Question: How can this be?

Comment: Do you use a URL locale param for language detection like `http://example.com/de/welcome` and `http://example.com/en/welcome`, a query parameter like `http://example.com/welcome?locale=de` or something else?

Comment: I was hoping that by setting it with I18n.locale=...   that would be sufficient. I am looking for a way without the url or param options (if that is possible at all).

Comment: Well, you need a way to **pass** your locale from one request to another. It must be stored or referenced somehow. Since a cookie or session storage is not recommended (a URL should be unique and tell about its content) the URL method is used for this (bonus: you get unique URLs for each language). I recommend the well written Rails Guide about Internationalization (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)

Comment: I changed the app to use the param based approach. Nevertheless, I am wondering why the above code did actually work (occasionally).

Comment: Probably because you set the `I18n.locale` for the current request. When you set the value, it is the same as setting the `I18n.locale` in, say, your `ApplicationController`. Maybe something is still in a kind of cache or so (might explain the 5-10 seconds)…